# Why i don't get an error?

Tags: java

In Java if I do the following I get an error

```
byte b = 50;
b = b * 2; // Error! Cannot assign an int to a byte!
```

Ok I understood why I got that error .
But now if I do `b*=2` I don't get any error. Why?

Comment: I'm assuming because b*=2 is automatically casting the result back as a byte, you could do `b = (byte) (b * 2);`

Comment: Lot of upvotes for a duplicate...

Comment: @MuratK. Voting ring?

Comment: Just in case: although the question was closed, you could still consider accepting one of the answers ... or go forward and delete the question altogether. Your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you make `b *= 2;` in fact this operation `*=` will cast your `int` to `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simply because there are different rules for narrowing conversions for = and *=.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) for details on widening in general; and then you go [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) to understand the difference for those *= operations.

You, see

```
b *= 2
```

works out as

```
b = (byte) ( (b) * 2 )
```

and that narrowing conversion doesn't play a role here.